# Access HTTP headers parameters using Mule Expression language

Tags: mule, expression

I am trying to access Http Header param 'Authorization' as part of an Mule Expression. i am trying to check if the Authorization parameter has been passed as part of header.

Below is the code that I am trying to use

```
message.inboundProperties.'http.headers'[authorization] == null
```

I am getting the following error.

> Execution of the expression
>   "message.inboundProperties.'http.headers'[authorization] == null"
>   failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).

Note: I am trying to use the above expression in the query part while creating a new simple custom policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as `[message.inboundProperties.authorization == null]`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to validate

> ```
> > <http:basic-security-filter securityProviders="memory-provider" realm="Valid
> > user credentials must be provided"></http:basic-security-filter>
> ```

If you just wanna check values #[inboundProperties.authorization == null]